# How to use $modal in my controller

Tags: angularjs

please find my below code,

**.js file**

```
var app = angular.module("rgMenu", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("MenuController",
  function ($scope, $http) {

  ///Some code here

});
```

Everything works fine above, but i want to use `$modal` so i use below code

**.html file**

```
src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.4.js"
```

**.js file**

```
var app = angular.module("rgMenu", ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("MenuController",
  function ($scope, $http, $modal) {

  ///Some code here

});
```

the moment i add `$modal` in controller my old code fails, it will not work. I have horizontal menu and it will not work.
Is it not possible to write `$modal` in same controller? How can i make use of `$modal` in above code?

Comment: Look at [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) they use $uibModal instead of $modal.

Comment: What is our bootstrap version?

Answer (score 0):

here is your solution:

**myModalContent.html**

```
<div>
  <div class="modal-header">
      <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in items">
        <a href="#" ng-click="$event.preventDefault(); selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="demo">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MenuController">
    <div class="text-center" style="margin-top:5%;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
      <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    angular.module('demo', ['ui.bootstrap'])
      .controller('MenuController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
         $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
         $scope.open = function (size) {
           var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
           templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
           controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
           size: size,
           resolve: {
             items: function () {
               return $scope.items;
             }
           }
         });
       modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
         $scope.selected = selectedItem;
       }, function () {
         $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
       });
     };
  }])
  .controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModalInstance', 'items', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items) {
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selected = {
      item: $scope.items[0]
    };
    $scope.ok = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
      $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```